# Find air compressed by a water tank

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

I have an open rooftop water tank in my house which has the water head at 10 meters above ground level. According to an online hydrostatic pressure calculator, I'm supposed to be getting about 14psi at the extreme bottom of the pipe opening. I don't have any test equipment or gauges to verify this but theoretical values are good enough. (*I'm within ~10m to the sea level*)

Now, if I add a sealed cylindrical water tank (~7.85L) in-line with the pipe at the bottom and close off the drain opening, then the air trapped inside the sealed tank at the bottom should start to compress. What I want to know is how much pressure will that trapped air get compressed to the max?

I know it might take a long time to reach that max pressure but I just want to know how much will the absolute max get. The pipes are 25mm in diameter.
I'm including a diagram that I've made to explain things a bit better.

Diagram (A) is my current setup with the water tank and pipe running to the bottom.

Diagram (B) is where the new in-line sealed cylindrical water tank gets attached to the pipes.

[image]

Comment: One question based on curiosity: why do you want to add the 7.85 L tank?

Comment: @DavidWhite So that I might get a little boost in water pressure when I open the valve allowing the trapped air to decompress. Wouldn't I?

Comment: I seriously doubt that you will see any recognizable boost in water flow.  The pressure in your attachment is provided by the water column that is above it, and that pressure will not exceed what the water column is already providing.

Comment: @DavidWhite It's okay, even if this setup fails it's original purpose I can always add a nozzle to the smaller tank and use the compressed air to inflate something.

Comment: Kokachi, if you try to pressurize the small tank with air, you will force water out of the small tank and into the large tank because that tank is open to the atmosphere.  Soon, air will be bubbling out of the large tank.  The pressure in the small tank will be very little changed, and you still will not get the boost in flow that you are looking for.

Comment: @DavidWhite  No I'm not trying to pressurize the smaller tank with additional air, I'm just trying to release the air that got compressed in it out through a nozzle. I understand what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let h be the height in cm that the water rises to in the small tank, and 100-h be the distance spanned by the air (in cm).  If the gauge pressure at the bottom is 14 psi, the gauge pressure in psi at the air interface is $$p_{ga}=14-\frac{h}{(2.54)(12)}0.4333=14-0.0142h$$where the 0.4333 is the rate of change of water pressure with elevation in psi/ft.  So the absolute pressure in psi at the interface with the air is $$P=p_{ga}+14.7=28.7-0.0142h$$From the ideal gas law, the absolute pressure of the air in the lower tank is $$P=\frac{100}{100-h}14.7$$where the original pressure in the lower tank was 14.7 psia.  Setting these pressures equal at the interface, we have:$$28.7-0.0142h=\frac{100}{100-h}14.7$$The solution to this equation is h = 52 cm.  Based on this, the air will occupy a little less than half the tank volume, and its pressure will be about 13.3 psig.

Comment: So the pressure in the lower tank to begin with was 14.7psi and then after compression this becomes 14.7+13.3 = 28psi right?

Comment: Thanks for the formula

Comment: Those would be the absolute pressures.  The gauge pressures in the lower tank would be 0 psig to start with, and 13.3 psig after compression.